# Displaying images encoded with base64 in react native

Tags: react-native, base64

I am new to react native and I am trying to display images encoded with base 64.

```
 <Image source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${element.img}`}}
                           style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}}/>
```

This is the mongoose scheme where I store my images

```
 img: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String,
},
```

And this is how I save them to database (photoData contains img):

```
this.setState({img:data.base64})
axios.post('uri', photoData, config)
```

Here is my img data : [img data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQBop.png)

data is returning back as buffer so using this

> **data:image/png;base64,${element.img}**

is not working. I tried using Buffer.from('','base64').toString('ascii') but still, image is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Your response is a buffer object you will have to use the below code to convert to base64 Image.

```
const data = Buffer.from(response, 'binary').toString('base64');

const base64Image = `data:image/png;base64,${data}`;

and then you can use the image normally
<Image source={{uri: base64Image}}/>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but, "The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined"  I am getting this error

Comment: you have a buffer in your object right ? img.data according to your image better try that

Comment: it says 'cannot read property 'data' of undefined' . I think it is a nested object and it can't reach data under the image.

Comment: The object you showed in the screenshot has a buffer better check that